# Dynamic workspace selection when importing state from s3

Tags: terraform

I am using below terraform datasource for importing shared state from s3. Terraform is giving me error " No stored state was found for the given workspace in the given backend". I am expecting terraform to pick up the workspace "dev-use1" as I have set the workspace using `terraform workspace select "dev-use1"`.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "shared_jobs_state" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket               = "cicd-backend"
    key                  = "analyticsjobs.tfstate"
    workspace_key_prefix = "pipeline/v2/db"
    region               = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Version = `Terraform v1.1.9 on darwin_arm64`

Comment: Have you actually created anything in the workspace prior to attempting to use the backend data source?

Comment: Yes there is state file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling the DEBUG in terraform by setting TF_LOG="DEBUG". I can see that s3 api call is giving 404 error.
from the request xml I can see that the prefix is wrong.
As a workaround I have done below changes to datasource.
Not sure this is the recommended way of doing but it works. There is less clarity in docs regards to this https://www.terraform.io/language/state/remote-state-data

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "shared_jobs_state" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket               = "cicd-backend"
    key                  = "pipeline/v2/db/${terraform.workspace}/analyticsjobs.tfstate"
    region               = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```